# How to enable Nimbus chrome plugin to capture screenshot in Katalon Recorder through Katalon Script

Tags: selenium-ide, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I want to access Chrome nimbus plugin to record video of test site and send link through mail. Chrome plugin is not accessible through recorder

In Chrome latest version Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: If it is possible with Mozilla firefox then it will helpful